# Can't change the CSS style after changing the CSS class with React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I try to make simple project with React .I have a TodoItem component. My expectation is to change the border color after the checkbox is checked. However, after checking the checkbox, my component doesn't change color. Am I doing something wrong? What steps should I take?

**App.jxs**

```
import './App.css'
import './components/TodoItem/TodoItem.jsx'
import TodoItem from './components/TodoItem/TodoItem.jsx'

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <TodoItem taskName={'Clean House'} statusInit={true} ></TodoItem>
      <TodoItem taskName={'Read Book'} statusInit={false} ></TodoItem>
      <TodoItem taskName={'Clean Bed'} statusInit ={true} ></TodoItem>
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

**TodoItem.jsx**

```
import "./TodoItem.css";
import { useState } from "react";

function TodoItem({ taskName, statusInit }) {

  const [status, setStatus] = useState(statusInit);
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  let myClass = statusInit ? 'done' : 'todo-item'
 

  function checkBoxOnChange(e) {
    setStatus(e.target.checked);
    setCount(count + 1);
    statusInit = e.target.checked;
    myClass = statusInit ? 'done' : 'todo-item'
  }
  return (
    <>
      <main className={myClass}>
        <input 
          checked={status}
          type="checkbox"
          onChange={checkBoxOnChange}
          id="todo-item-status"
        />
        <p>{`${status}`}</p>
        <p>{taskName}</p>
        <p>{count}</p>
      </main>
    </>
  );
}

export default TodoItem;
```

**TodoItem.css**

```
.todo-item{
    width: 300px;
    margin: 16px;
    padding: 16px; 
    border: solid royalblue 2px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.done{
    width: 300px;
    margin: 16px;
    padding: 16px; 
    border: solid green 2px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

**EDIT**

I found another solution for my answer. Maybe myClass should be a state, as shown in my code below:

```
import "./TodoItem.css";
import { useState } from "react";

function TodoItem({ taskName, statusInit }) {

  const [status, setStatus] = useState(statusInit);
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [myClass, setMyClass] = useState(statusInit ? 'done' : 'todo-item'); 
  

  function checkBoxOnChange(e) {
    setStatus(e.target.checked);
    setCount(count + 1);
    setMyClass(e.target.checked ? 'done' : 'todo-item')
  }
  
  return (
    <>
      <main className={myClass}>
        <input 
          checked={status}
          type="checkbox"
          onChange={checkBoxOnChange}
          id="todo-item-status"
        />
        <p>{`${status}`}</p>
        <p>{taskName}</p>
        <p>{count}</p>
      </main>
    </>
  );
}

export default TodoItem;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create a variable. Apply conditional className based on state, it will automatically re-render with different styles.

```
<main className={status ? "done" : "todo-item"}></main>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `statusInit` value will remain true as it is a `prop` from the parent Component. Try log the value of `statusInit` value in the jsx part so that you can find the reason for not changing class properly.

```
//In the TodoItem.js
return (
    <>
      {console.log(statusInit)}
    </>
  );
```

As you are maintaining a separate state called `status`, you can use that instead `statusInit`.

```
//TodoItem.js
import "./TodoItem.css";
import { useState } from "react";

function TodoItem({ taskName, statusInit }) {

  const [status, setStatus] = useState(statusInit);
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  let myClass = status ? 'done' : 'todo-item'
 

  function checkBoxOnChange(e) {
    setStatus(e.target.checked);
    setCount(count + 1);
    myClass = status ? 'done' : 'todo-item'
  }
  return (
    <>
      <main className={myClass}>
        <input 
          checked={status}
          type="checkbox"
          onChange={checkBoxOnChange}
          id="todo-item-status"
        />
        <p>{`${status}`}</p>
        <p>{taskName}</p>
        <p>{count}</p>
      </main>
    </>
  );
}

export default TodoItem;
```

This will render the style properly as it gets updated correctly on `onChange` event.

Comment: May I can ask why my code doesn’t work even the InitStatus is true after setState called?

Comment: Because `setState` is the state-updater function of `status` i.e., it updates only the value of `status` not the value of `statusInit`. `statusInit` is a prop value and can't be updated in child component and Its value needs to be updated in the parent component and it can be done by a function declared in its parent and calling it using prop.

Comment: I change my code as the same your example but it still doesn't work

Comment: Could you share the code of `TodoItem.js`? It works fine for me - changes green when checked and blue on uncheck ,also count gets incremented.  Double check for correct filepath.

Answer (score 0):

Your component is not updating the `myClass` variable when the checkbox is checked. This is because you are directly assigning the `statusInit` value to `myClass` during initialization, and later changing `statusInit` in the `checkBoxOnChange` function doesn't update `myClass`.

To fix this, you should use the `status` state to determine the class dynamically. Here's the corrected version of your **TodoItem** component

```
import "./TodoItem.css";
import { useState } from "react";

function TodoItem({ taskName, statusInit }) {

  const [status, setStatus] = useState(statusInit);
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
 
  function checkBoxOnChange(e) {
    setStatus(e.target.checked);
    setCount(count + 1);
  }

  const myClass = status ? 'done' : 'todo-item';

  return (
    <>
      <main className={myClass}>
        <input 
          checked={status}
          type="checkbox"
          onChange={checkBoxOnChange}
          id="todo-item-status"
        />
        <p>{`${status}`}</p>
        <p>{taskName}</p>
        <p>{count}</p>
      </main>
    </>
  );
}

export default TodoItem;
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't work for me. Even after moving myClass and making it const, it still doesn't work